# Angular - Tests

Tags: angular, visual-studio, testing

1. I have made a new project in Angular using cmd "ng new app". I typed "npm test" and then I had 3 tests that were succeed. What am I supposed to do to see those tests in Test Eplorator in Visual Studio? Should I open a project somehow cause i used to open it by "Open a local folder".
2. Does anyone has any public repository with an example of project with test written cause i wanted to learn how to run them in Visual Studio?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests are describe en .spec.ts files.

When you call npm test it starts karma and looks for those files and execute tests.

If you want to run individual test case you should prefix the test with an f:

it('should bla bla bla', () => {});

to
fit('should bla bla bla', () => {});

Comment: If I write the tests you mentioned above, am I going to see them automatically in Test Explorer?

Comment: Yes, you need the Test Explorer UI plugin and the Angular/Karma Test Explorer adapter, you can install it from the extensions tab of visual studio code.